# How to prevent auto character encoding in .NET

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

Using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010, I have two files:
"test2.aspx" and "test2.aspx.vb".
The aspx file is basically as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"   AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="App_test2" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta id="meta1" runat="server" name="description" />
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="text1" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

The vb file is basically like this:

```
meta1.Attributes("charset") = "UTF-8"
meta1.Attributes("content") = "I'm a description tag"
text1.InnerText = "&'<>"
```

This all displays as expected in the browser, but the source code when the page is rendered looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta id="meta1" name="description" content="I&#39;m a description tag" charset="UTF-8"></meta>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="text1" id="text2">&amp;&#39;&lt;&gt;</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something I can do so the source code doesn't escape characters like "&", "'", "<", and ">" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  If it didn't convert those characters, the browser would incorrectly interpret them as commands instead of data.  It shouldn't be an issue for you because it is always converted back to the character data in code. text2.Text would contain the values you want, not the escaped data.

Comment: That's interesting. I noticed on the homepage for Yahoo!, their meta tag for description contains an unescaped apostrophe. I wondered how they did this without hardcoding it into an index.html file. Any clue how they did that?
Re: text2- that should've said text1. Sorry for any confusion, particularly mine. Thanks!

Comment: the apostrophe is one you can get away with in a string.  The Yahoo page you are looking at is probably hard coded that was whereas the .aspx page you are working with goes through the asp.net processor.  Search engines know to convert those escaped code to the proper string and it should not affect anything you do.